# Efficient way of exporting large R dataset to excel

Tags: python, r, excel, export-to-excel

As title, I have a dataset with about 13000 rows and 255 columns (actually I have more than 255 columns but `RODBC` package seems to limit the number of columns exported to 255, so I trimmed it a bit) that need to be exported to xls/xlsx file.

I tried `RODBC` and `xlsx` package, both takes more than 5 minutes for export. I wonder if there is any other more efficient way of doing this?

I knew a little bit of python (using python to connect to outlook for listing emails in mailbox), if there is way for export using python instead, it is welcomed also.

#### update 01

Quite a few suggested using csv, it may not very possible in my case because there is a field containing free text that I cannot control what kind of character is entered in that field, making selection of separator difficult.

#### update 02

thank you for the suggestions, but I found that the R packages are fine only if the dataframe is relatively small and it is even slow for dataframe with all columns being character. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be in XLS/XLSX? Could you do CSV?

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Excel.   Anyway, like BlueMagister said, write to CSV and let the fools at the other end import the data.

Comment: WriteXLS package is another alternative.  You will need to try it to find out if its fast enough for you.

Comment: You can add quotation around text when export into csv file. The quotation will be removed when import into excel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of options:

1. Use `xlsx` with mutliple sheets (you've tried this and it's too slow, I know)
2. Use `write.csv` should be faster and it's readable by Excel
3. Use `odbcConnectExcel2007` within `RODBC`
4. Use the package `bigmemory` to help you manage the large dataframe, especially if you can make it into a sparse matrix
5. `XLConnect` which worked for [this guy](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-export-a-big-data-frame-to-excel-2010-file-xlsx-td4642223.html) with the same problem
6. Write it to a SQL datatabase with `RODBC` or `RPostgreSQL`, etc and then make a connection to the DB within Excel. I do this a lot. Here's a [related resource](http://www.r-bloggers.com/postgresql-excel-r-and-a-really-big-data-set/).
7. Use [`Pandas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955298/efficient-way-of-exporting-large-r-dataset-to-excel)
8. Create a `tab-delimited` text file and then import it to Excel: `write.table (table,sep="\t",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,file=file.name)`
9. Use [`fread`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/fread)
10. Try a [cloud-based solution](http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/new-fast-excel-to-process-billions-of-rows-via-the-cloud) (I'm not sure if this will actually be faster, but it would at least be a trendy solution with extra benefits such as providing a nice way to store your data safely and let you query whatever you need from it using Excel on any computer)
11. [`RExcel`](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html)
12. `XLLoop`

Finally, here's [a nice little article](http://www.thertrader.com/2014/02/11/a-million-ways-to-connect-r-and-excel/) on "A Million Ways to Connect R and Excel" which you may find useful, though I think I've actually given you more options than the article does.

I would start with the most simple solutions, like `fread`, then work your way to the relatively more complicated solutions if you're still not getting the results you want.

Depending on the exact nature of your project, you might even benefit from parallelism or multicore processing. Those don't boost your I/O speed in most cases, but it could speed up any processing/transformation of your data which takes place in your process, thus making your overall data pipeline faster.

`Python` is also very well-equipped to handle this problem, but there are so many solutions within `R`, hopefully you won't need to resort to switching languages just to write out data. Still, you could try

1. `XlsxWriter` in Constant Memory mode, or
2. Optimized Reader and Writer of the `openpyxl` package

   if you want to try a Python-based solution.

Answer (score -2):

try to use openxlsx package its quite fast.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf

1. Install package openxlsx
2. load the library openxlsx
3. use `write.xlsx()` or `writeData()` command to write into xlsx file

A small example of basic operations using openxlsx library
taken from openxlsx documentation

```
`## setup a workbook with 3 worksheets
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "Sheet 1", gridLines = FALSE)
writeDataTable(wb = wb, sheet = 1, x = iris)
addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "mtcars (Sheet 2)", gridLines = FALSE)
writeData(wb = wb, sheet = 2, x = mtcars)
addWorksheet(wb = wb, sheetName = "Sheet 3", gridLines = FALSE)
writeData(wb = wb, sheet = 3, x = Formaldehyde)
worksheetOrder(wb)
names(wb)
worksheetOrder(wb) <- c(1,3,2) # switch position of sheets 2 & 3
writeData(wb, 2, 'This is still the "mtcars" worksheet', startCol = 15)
worksheetOrder(wb)
names(wb) ## ordering within workbook is not changed
saveWorkbook(wb, "worksheetOrderExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
worksheetOrder(wb) <- c(3,2,1)
saveWorkbook(wb, "worksheetOrderExample2.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)`
```

Gani

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10779647)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will write an example for it.